# Dynamic LinkButton Click event never appears on the resulting anchor

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm currently trying to add to each day of a .net calendar control one dynamic linkbutton (on the dayRender event). The problem I have is that the linkbutton href does not appear. **It's not a problem of the linkbutton event not firing, the href= doesn't even appear, so it doesn't fire any postback.** This means that the button looks like this in the html part:

```
<a class="delete79" ID="Delete_2014-09-01"> Delete </a>
```

My code looks like this:

```
protected void MyCalendar79_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    List<MenuDia> dayList = new List<MenuDia>();
    foreach (var itemMenu in ListMenuDays)
    {
        if (itemMenu.Dia.CompareTo(e.Day.Date) == 0)
        {
            dayList.Add(itemMenu);
        }
    }
    LinkButton deleteButton = new LinkButton();
    deleteButton.CssClass = "delete79";
    deleteButton.Text = "Delete";
    deleteButton.ID = "Delete79_" + dayList[0].Dia.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    deleteButton.Click += delegate(object o, System.EventArgs a)
    {
         //simple stuff here, tried putting simple generic response.redirect
         //and stuff like that but it wasn't the problem
    };
}
```

I don't wanna sound rude but don't tell me that it's because I'm using a delegate instead of an eventhandler. First of all I tried changing that already (same thing happened) and second I usually do it like this when it's super simple so I don't have to create a separate method.

Also, I've tried changing the ID to something more predictable (Delete_+a simple index), that's not the problem unfortunately =(.

Any other ideas? Maybe it's because I'm doing it on dayrender and you can't do it there? How can I achieve the same thing then?

Comment: What is the `Type` of `deleteButton`?

Comment: Where/how do you create (instantiate) `deleteButton`?

Comment: Note that the ID you're generating is invalid. Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid (per MSDN).

Comment: Where do you add the `deleteButton` to the `Controls` collection?

Comment: @M4n Is that so? Anyway I tried to put a super generic ID and it didn't work either =(

Comment: @M4n Oh btw I instantiate linkbutton one line before... didn't copy it. My bad

Comment: @demoncodemonkey The type is LinkButton as said in title/post. Sorry I didn't copy the line. It's edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah I found the problem. MSDN page says:

> Because the DayRender event is raised while the Calendar control is
>   being rendered, you cannot add a control that can also raise an event,
>   such as LinkButton. You can only add static controls, such as
>   System.Web.UI.LiteralControl, Label, Image, and HyperLink.

That's the problem. I will do a hack manually that generates the same postback of a hidden linkbutton. Thanks everyone!